# GTA V on Dell 7560 i7 with 940MX

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, system-requirements

1. Graphics Memory: 4 GB
2. Graphic Processor: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 940MX
3. Processor: Intel Core i7-7500U (7th Gen)
4. Game is loading from HDD

I have fairly recently bought the Dell 7560 with the aforementioned specifications. I have bought an original copy of GTA V. And I have installed and kept updated the GeForce Game Ready Driver.

However, I am facing a lot of lag and a very bad experience while playing the game even with minimum settings. This is just frustrating. Just loading the game fires up the fans as if I am launching Falcon Heavy.

The game is installed on my hard drive.

My question is, are there any software which I should install to optimise my gaming experience?

How do I enhance my gaming experience? Any tips? Thanks

Comment: I dunno.  The problem is, that thread is pretty accurate for desktops, but I think this user is victim to the twisted marketing of laptops; he might still be lost after reading that thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the 940M is a weaker video card than most of the 900 series from nVidia, that's only likely to be a part of the problem.

Some 940m setups do not use discrete memory, and instead share off of the system's RAM.  This can contribute to slowdowns and is worth a look to see if this is happening.  If it is, try to throttle the behavior so that at least 3GB is left available to your system and the rest for your video card.

Here's your big issue:

"Processor: Intel Core i7-7500U (7th Gen)"

The i7 is a great processor.  I use 2nd gen and 8th gen ones at home.  The problem is that Intel did some shady nonsense with their mobile platform marketing.  This is specific to the suffix: U vs HQ.

An i7 HQ functions as a proper i7.  It stands for "High Quality", to my understanding, and is a nice, albeit expensive, mobile processor.

The i7 U is dirty pool.  It literally means "Ultra-Low Power".  It is actually a dual-core processor more similar to an i3 in structure and performance.  They benchmark 30-50% slower than the HQ and HK models of the same line. They are placed in laptops to conserve battery life, but marketed as an i7 to boost sales.  GTA V is pretty CPU-heavy, as are most open-world games. You can find intel's processor naming schema [here.](https://www.intel.in/content/www/in/en/processors/processor-numbers.html)

Unfortunately, you're sort of stuck.  You'll need a different processor, and laptops are more challenging when it comes to user-service than desktops. I recommend upgrading the machine altogether when you can, as the 940M is an older mobile card that will struggle with newer games above moderate settings.